# Простой вопрос GUI Action Listener: как изменить имя кнопки?

Tags: java, gui

public class GUI2 implements ActionListener {

```
private static JPanel panel;
JButton button1;
JButton button4;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI2 gui = new GUI2();
    gui.go();
}

public void go (){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test2 Frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, panel);

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Button1");
    JButton button4 = new JButton("Button4");
    panel.add(button1);
    panel.add(button4);

    button1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    // работает, меняет имя button1
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            button1.setText("I have been clicked1");
        }
    });


    button4.addActionListener(this);
}

// ошибка: NPE (должен менять имя button4)
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    button4.setText("I have been clicked4");
}
```

Comment: Что такое `ButtonListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы обьявили **поля** `button1`, `button4`, но в методе `go()` "переопределили" их **локальными** переменными. При этом они остались инициализированными значениями по умолчанию `null`. Это и приводит к `NPE`.

Если хотите кнопки использовать как локальные переменные, то ваш метод `actionPerformed` будет вот таким:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ((JButton) e.getSource()).setText("I have been clicked4");
}
```

Если поля, то инициализируйте их при объявлении или в конструкторе